# Grails twitter-bootstrap plugin not updating assets

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grails

I have updated the version of the twitter-bootstrap plugin to 3.3.5 but the assets/javascripts directory still shows the bootstrap.js file as v2.3.2. Any idea why this may be happening? Does the plugin check the grails version? I am on grails 2.4.4.

Comment: Have you ran the grails commands `asset-clean` and `asset-precompile` to force a refresh?

Comment: So it turned out we had the bootstrap js files in the webapp directory and they were being picked up instead of the plugin. Cleaned up the js libraries and all is good. Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A developer had added the bootstrap files to the assets directory. The assets directory is not supposed to have any files from the plugins. The asset plugin will pick up the necessary dependencies (js, css) from the plugin directories. Removing those from the assets directory up fixed the problem as it let the assets plugin pickup those files from the bootstrap plugin which is the correct behavior.